# Visual Studio Code autoimport extension

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I am looking for a solution on a problem I am having in VSCode. In fact, I was using an extension which was making auto - import between models and so on in Django Projects. The thing is, I had to reset my Mac and I forgot which extension that was.
It was something that was also able to make all the used imports let's say with a more vivid color on VSCode and also was making all the "unused" variables (the one that were not used in the context in django or other variables) with less vivid colors.

This extension also changed the color of the models in Django too, giving all the type of DB entries (like Charfield or Foreign Key) a different color.

[image]

I know it's a little bit tricky to understand but I tried to find out which extension that was but I really don't remember.
Thank you very much for any help

Comment: the vivid colors is "semantic highlighting", not all Themes support that, choose a different one (a default one), have you searched the marketplace for `django`

Comment: Yeah, actually the problem is more present in Python. I was using this extension a lot but I couldn't find it anymore. I really have no clue the name it had. I don't know, maybe Pylance, but I installed it and it's not working.

Comment: your request is very django specific, so it should be a keyword in the marketplace